# Books / Lectures on these types of questions

Tags: inequality, contest-math, absolute-value

I was wondering which branch / part of mathematics deals with inequalities & questions like the ones I've linked, and if there are any books or lectures that surround the topic. I've tried looking for an answer but I can't really find anything which satisfies what I'm looking for.

question 1:

Given $a\geq 0$ , find all solutions for $a$.

$x^2+|x-a| - |x+a| = 0$

question 2:

solve the following equation.

$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x²-1}} = 2 - \sqrt x$

I was able to solve this one but it took me like 25 minutes to figure out.

If you need more info ask away and I'll try to find more examples / answer your questions, thanks!

Comment: "Books and lectures on inequalities" is an entirely different topic than the two problems you state.  For the problems you state, take cases based on whether $x-a$ and $x+a$ are positive or negative; or where $x \ge 0$, $x^2-1 \ge 0$, and $x+\sqrt{x^2-1} \ge 0$.

Comment: Edited the title, don't really know what branch of maths these types of quetions belong to. From the answer you gave me, would I be in the ballpark assuming that these types of questions fall under "competitive maths" and lower level analysis,or is that not a good way to phrase it? Thanks for taking time to respond =)

Comment: I would list these things as questions in algebra/precalculus. Granted that contest math seems to have more than its share of these sorts of questions.